# How to setup http redirect for links to other urls on my site?

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, cname-record

I'm trying to use cname and http redirect to hide that I'm linking to other domains on my site.  I know how to setup the cname through my hosting service, but I'm unsure how to setup the http redirects.  Do I need to setup each redirect link in the .htaccess file?  Is there an easier and more efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you are using the Apache webserver. You'd want to use the Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) modules.

Because you want to hide the original domain you have to proxy through your webserver. Note that this feature is not available at some hosting providers for security/abuse reasons. Also note that mosts companies don't allow you to proxy their sites (content) for fishing reasons.

In your .htaccess file you can than use mod_rewrite to proxy requests to other websites:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule foo(.*) http://www.example.com/bar/$1 [P,L]
```

- Match agains *Servername/DirectoryName/**Foo***[Wildcard everything]
- Rewrite to http://www.example.com/bar/[Insert matched wildcard]
- Proxy the request [P]
- Stop rewriting [L]

To proxy a remote image as if it's on your server you would use:

```
RewriteRule ^myimage.jpg$ http://www.example.com/itsactuallymine.jpg [P,L]
```